# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 when running npm start in React Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

Whenever I try to run the 'npm start' command, I get this weird error. It was working fine a few hours ago and now it simply won't start. I've tried reinstalling Typescript but that didn't work.

This is what I get from my terminal:
console log[image]

Here's the code I've been working on Dashboard.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import PieChart from '../components/PieChart/PieChart'
import ColumnChart from '../components/ColumnChart/ColumnChart'
import NavItem from '../components/NavItem/NavItem'

import '../styles/DashBoard.scss'
import dashboardIcon from '../assets/images/dashboard.svg'
import exitIcon from '../assets/images/exitIcon.svg'
import footerStrip from '../assets/images/footerStrip.svg'
import headerStrip from '../assets/images/headerStrip.svg'

const DashBoard = () => {
return (
    <>
    <aside>
        <header>
            <img src={headerStrip} alt="Top header green strip" />
        </header>
        <nav>
            <section id="mainNavigation">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavItem 
                            alt='Dashboard menu item'
                            path='/dashboard'
                            src={dashboardIcon}
                            >Dashboard</NavItem>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section id="programmer">
                <header>
                    <span>PROGRAMADOR</span>
                </header>
                <p>Edgar Marques</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavItem
                            alt='Exit platform icon'
                            src={exitIcon}
                            path='/'
                            >Sair</NavItem>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>

        <footer>
            <img src={footerStrip} alt="Bottom navigation green strip" />
            <div>Uma plataforma <p>NEW WAVE</p></div>
        </footer>
    </aside>

    <main>

    </main>
    </>
)
```

}

```
export default DashBoard
```

And here is NavItem.tsx. I'm using static data to implement the front-end first. I'm not calling JSON.parse anywhere on the code.

```
import style from './NavItem.module.scss'

type NavItemData = {
    children: any
    src: any 
    path: string 
    alt: string 
}

const NavItem = (props: NavItemData) => {
    return (
        <div className={style.navWrapper}>
            <a href={props.path} className={style.navLink}>
                <img src={props.src} alt={props.alt}/>
                {props.children}
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavItem
```

Comment: Not much we can do with just an error message. somewhere you are calling JSON.parse and supplying an invalid json string. You need to show us some code so we can help.

Comment: I've updated the post

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this error by deleting *node_modules* folder and then run *npm install*.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a comma after each of these:

```
type NavItemData = {
    children: any,
    src: any,
    path: string,
    alt: string 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't work here :(

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by creating a new folder and pulling the project from my repository. For some reason, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the node_modules and npm install solves this..